# Default value pre-selected in select box with ng-options

Tags: sql, angularjs, sql-server, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

I am trying to get default value selected (from database) in my select box using `ng-options`.

#### My view

```html
<select class="form-control samlength modalinput" 
        ng-options="p.procid as p.procname for p in processes track by p.procid" 
        ng-model="p.procid">
  <option value="">-- choose an option --</option>
</select>
```

where `p.procid` is a value received from the database.

#### My data

```
procid  procname    time
    1   MyProcess   2018-05-30 13:34:54.097 3003162
    3   Testing     2018-05-31 18:31:32.467 3003162
```

If selected `procid` is 3, how can I get it to be selected by default?

FYI - I have tried multiple answers given in other threads. I have also tried `ng-init` but nothing helped.

Comment: your syntax is wrong. The `ng-model` should be a unique, different variable, e.g. `ng-model="selectedProcess"`. Then you can select a default process as `$scope.selectedProcess = $scope.processes[index]`. The index would be the one with `procid` as 3 (find it with `.indexOf()` or something similar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep your HTML as:

```
<select class="form-control samlength modalinput" 
        ng-options="p.procid as p.procname for p in processes track by p.procid" 
        ng-model="selectedProcess">
  <option value="">-- choose an option --</option>
</select>
```

Now if we have a requirement to select a particular object in the array. We can do that by iterating through the array and comparing value at the given key:

```
function functiontofindIndexByKeyValue(arraytosearch, key, valuetosearch) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arraytosearch.length; i++) {
      if (arraytosearch[i][key] == valuetosearch) {
        return i;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Call this function as:

```
var index = functiontofindIndexByKeyValue($scope.processes, "procid", procid);
$scope.selectedProcess = $scope.processes[index];
alert(index);
```

Hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

Update your html code to this:

```
<select ng-model="processSelected" 
     ng-options="p.procname for p in processes track by p.procid">
</select>
```

Then in controller initialise your model value as:

```
$scope.processSelected = $scope.processes[1];
```

Where `$scope.processes` is an array of process objects.

[**Plunker Example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/pojyJO7H3plVaa6Jw9iv?p=preview)